# Unity 2D Change sprite from a list of sprites

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gameObject as a sprite in my 2D game, and then in a different script I have an array of 2d textures, in a sprite array. I simple want to change the sprite's sprite property but get the error 'object reference not set to an instance of a object'.
Here is the line throwing the error, which is in one script.:

```
this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = GameObject.Find ("UIM").GetComponent<Manager> ().spriteImages [1];
```

While the array, is in a different script, attached to the object 'UIM' in a different scene to the one I am trying to access it from (not sure if this causes the problem), is defined with:

```
public Sprite[] spriteImages = new Sprite[5];
```

Why am I getting this error? I have filled the array with the textures so cannot see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a script & variable from another scene. In unity whenever you load a new scene your old scene values will be destroyed and that will lead to 'object reference not set to an instance of a object' error. You can bring the tell the unity not to destroy the object which you will need in future scenes by calling [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html). This will allow the gameobject to persist across the scene. 
One more thing you have to keep in mind is that if you are returning to the old scene where you marked the Object UIManager as dontdestroyonload then make sure the next instances are deleted and managed from the scene which is reloaded else whenever you keep on reloading the old scene with UImanager it will keep on piling up the instances of it across the scenes. The example in the unity with dontdestroyonload should be more than enough to solve your problems. Here is a snippet shown in Unity API which you can refer:

```
void Awake()
{
    GameObject[] objs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("music");

    if (objs.Length > 1)
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
public GameObject[] objs = 
      SceneManager.GetSceneByName(sceneToLoad).GetRootGameObjects(); 
foreach(GameObject go in objs)
{
    if(go.name == "UIM")
    {
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = 
          go.GetComponent<Manager> ().spriteImages [1];
        break;
    }
}
```